# Angular 7 + ShadowDOM - Loading strategies for @angular/material skins

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular7, shadow-dom

I'm wanting to do an `Angular 7` application with all of the `encapsulation` set to `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` - and that's all well and good.

But I cannot seem to find any sort of reliable reference that shows a good way to approach this with regards to skinning things like `@angular/material`. Since global styles are worthless, I cannot just follow the rules at [Theming Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) because they ...well, don't work.

Has anyone managed to get this working in a decent fashion?

Comment: We use custom angular themes in our app. I have very little issues. The only real issue I had was with the `cdk-overlay` and some of the other angular material-specific components. I haven't played with shadow dom yet though. With the exception of a few components, everything has the default ViewEncapsulation. Some had to be marked as None just to hack some styling. I will mention that it took a while to figure out how to actually use angular theming correctly.

Comment: Thank you - but I am very familiar with how to do it using the `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`. It's specifically with `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` that challenges begin to arise because the two are fundamentally very different.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into similar issue. However, at the angular element component where I was using `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDOM` - I had to import the theme.scss that I was using in angular.json `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";` in the components scss file.

And, things worked.

Answer (score 1):

I also experimented with shadow dom v1. However [as stated here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3386) Angular Material depends on global css, which they will eventually change in Jan 2020 when they drop support for IE11.
Unfortunately I could not find any real workaround, once shadow dom was used that component would always have style glitches.

Comment: Can you point where you read that Angular Material will drop support for IE11 in Jan 2020?

Comment: Oh I see its here but i read it as a "maybe we will drop support": https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7374

Comment: I read it in a material2 timeline with upcoming features somewhere but I couldnt find it again. However here is a post where they confirm the date Jan 2020 (https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4352#issuecomment-367151845).

Comment: This is still pretty ridiculous. I can accept if third party suites can't use the ShadowDOM, but Angular's own first party library can't either.